# Tropical wood decking in Cfa climate: is kiln-drying really a must?

Tags: outdoor

Japan has mostly a Cfa climate. The average value of the equilibrium moisture content of Japan was 15%, and the numerical value range was 12-19%.

Typical air-dried ipe wood has a moisture content of 15%.

A local supplier insist that their wood is better than their competitors because it's kiln-dried. Given the MC & EMC above, it doesn't look to me that a deck made of ipe would want to lose much moisture.

In this climate, does kiln-drying really have any obvious benefit, or is it basically marketing hype?

Comment: I dont think there us any benefit for you.